# PyQt5 - Emit Signal and Change color Font?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a Python application whereby I pass an object through to a QThread, where a signal is emitted back to the UI in a loop.

I am wondering if it is possible to emit a signal back to the main loop, and amend the font color depending on the returned value?

For example:

In the QThread Class...

```
if self.status != "True":
    # Set State
    state = "Failed"
    result = "Fail"
    reason = "I/O Failure"

    # Emit State
    self.state.emit(state)
    self.result.emit(result)
    self.reason.emit(reason)

    sleep(1)
else:
    print("All is Good")
```

From here, if the `result` is Fail, then I would like to amend the color to Red or color the Background of the QTableWidgetItem Cell a light red or similar, previously, I have done this as such...

```
status.setForeground(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor('red')))
status.setBackground(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 204, 204)))
font = QFont(results.status, weight=QFont.Bold)
```

But this was on the original QTableWidgetItem creation, and not from within the Thread, is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Operations that interact with the GUI should be in the main thread.  So your best bet is to connect a slot in your widget to the signals coming from the thread and then implement the color change in your widget.  The signal can tell the widget what color to set, but the actual color change should be done in the main thread.  That is my understanding anyway.

Comment: I figured as much... I will see if I can emit a "status_color" signal based on the result to the main thread and check there.

Comment: If it helps, when using signals, you can emit `object` types such as *lists* or *dictionaries*, if you're not using them anymore on the `QThread`. This way you can pass mulitple variables to a single signal callback. If the value of `result` signal is relevant inside the other signals' callbacks, you can pass multiple variables to them at once, instead of triggering a new event. (Example: `self.state.emit([state, result])` or `self.reason.emit([reason, result])`.

Comment: @animanick the reason I'm telling you that is because you're emitting 3 different signals at the same time, as if you wanted to execute a single callback with 3 arguments. If that's what you want to do, you may need only one signal inside the `QThread`.